# What do the read colors in IGV mean?

Tags: sequence-alignment, visualization, igv

I was looking at a bam file in the IGV viewer and saw:

[image: IGV screenshot]

What do the different read colors mean? Why is one read a light blue color, another green, another aquamarine (?), another purple and another two orange? What do these different read colors represent? The [IGV docs](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/UserGuide) have sections on interpreting color [by insert size](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/interpreting_insert_size), p[air orientation](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/interpreting_pair_orientations), [bisulphide mode](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/interpreting_bisulfite_mode), [splice junctions](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/splice_junctions) and [sashimi plot](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/Sashimi), but none of them seems to be describing what I'm looking at there.

More generally, where are all these default behaviors documented? Are they somewhere in http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/UserGuide and I'm missing them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that these are reads with their mates found on other chromosomes? That's [the part of the IGV documentation](http://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/interpreting_insert_size) which seems to make sense in this context:

> [image: color codes from IGV docs]
>
> for paired end reads that are coded by the chromosome on which their mates can be found